# Need a way to use private methods of a class from another class

Tags: private, internal

I have class "A" that holds some methods that i need to use in another class (class "B"), 
that holds the instance of class A. Those methods in class "A" can be internal because i have the two classes in the same assembly but i need them to be private because class "B" is the only class that i want to use those methods.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ClassB: ClassA` (so a derived class) you can declare those methods as `protected`, so accessible only to derived classes.

Exmaple:

```
public class ClassA
{
    protected void FooA() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
    internal void FooB() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public void Foo() { FooA(); }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.FooA(); // Error, because you don't see it
        classA.FooB(); // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't want ClassB to inherit from classA cus classA has lots of functions that i have no need in classB, and its logically uncurrect.

Comment: @talzach: It's logically uncorrect what you're trying to do: why do you project a class with some method that could be used **only** from another class? Refactor your code, maybe using virtual classes/methods  or interfaces.

Comment: @talzach: I really can't answer this question knowing nothing about classes and what they're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could always mark the methods in Class A as internal and then set the InternallyVisibleTo flag in the assembly information file?